# unable to launch iis express webserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, razor

am making  ASP MVC3 website 
every time i run my website it show me this error and it doesn't run
(unable to launch the iis express web server 
failed to register URL "HTTP/~" for this site "my project name" application "/".Error description:Access denied. (0x80070005))

I am using Visual Studio 2013
Windows 8
IIS 8 express

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer and choose "Properties". Then, under the tab for "Web" and the section "Servers", make sure the "Project Url" field is set to a valid fully-qualified URL (i.e. `http://localhost:12345`, where the port portion is not in use by another web application). Also, ensure that "Override application root URL" is unchecked, or if it is checked and you want it that way, that the field there is also a valid fully-qualified URL.